# incremental memory consumption on azure functions app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, python-3.8, azure-eventhub

On azure functions app which is running on the app service plan we notice that memory is significantly increasing (from ~100MB to 3GB).

The function app is written in Python and is triggered whenever new event is received in the events hub.

I've tried to profile memory based on [azure's official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/python-memory-profiler-reference) and there are several weird parts I've noticed:

1. on each new event invocation, the function memory is being increased by several KB / MB
2. for example, when variables hold data, inside the Python function, as logs show the memory is not released (?)
3. over time this little increments add up to high memory usage.

It would be helpful if you can suggest possible solutions or any further debug methods.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, tried that same profiler  but not many hints there either. I'm currently removing objects with `del`, still no luck. I'm tempted to believe something in the Azure runtime is leaking memory

Answer (score 0):

After some time & too many profiling sessions, it seems like the issue is related to the logging library we're using in the project (python logzio), they have an special section for the serverless deployment, the implementation aims to flush the loggers. Once the logzio flusher correctly flushes the loggers, the increased memory consumption between calls is not an issue any more. This solves my problem, caused by logzio logger integration.

[This is the docs for reference](https://github.com/logzio/logzio-python-handler#serverless-platforms).